# Cox model plotting error (NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Tags: r

This is my cox model
`model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data=data)`

and I use `cox.zph()` function to test the assumptions:
`forplot <- cox.zph(model)`

`plot(forplot)`
OR 
`ggcoxzph(forplot)`

When I try to plot the model, I keep getting the same error :

```
Error in qr.default(t(const)) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

I think it has to do with the `spline::ns` part of the function,
I'm just not sure how to solve this issue. Can anyone help me or knows what I could try please?

Comment: Try `data <- hablar::rationalize(data)` before everything else and see if that helps you. It converts all Inf and NaN to NA. But it sounds like you need to romove or fill the missing values for your model to work?

Comment: Tried and still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue, and solved it by lowering the degrees of freedom for the smooth (i.e., by setting the `df` argument of `plot.cox.zph()` to the highest possible value for which a plot could be produced through trial and error).